# Characteristic and elements of quotient ring $Z[i]/(2+2i)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't understand correct answer of one example.

There is defined set $Z[i] = \{a+bi | a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$  and I need to find characteristic of quotient ring $Z[i]/(2+2i)$. What is the correct answer? I found that is 4, and I don't understand why. According to definition I thought that it is 0, but it isn't. I also read some questions on this site, but i am still note sure. Could someone help me?

Next question is to find all elements of mentioned quotient ring. I have these: 1,-1,i,-i,1+i,1-i,-1+i,-1-i. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

In that ring $$1+1+1+1=4=(2+2i)(1-i)=0$$

Comment: The characteristic might still be $2$.

Comment: @lhf And the ring could be the zero ring too.

Comment: Sure, that's what missing in the argument.

Comment: @lhf Do you have difficulties completing it? Which part are you unable to do?

Comment: No. But you may want to incude that part in your answer.